# How do I make the program track user inputs at the loop code?

Tags: python, loops

I'm struggling to code an if-statement series for an arbitrary and stupid game I designed called 'guessing game'. What should I add so that one loop compares the previous and the current answer and show it on console?

```
import random
    
listte = range(1, 21) # list contains 1-20
number = random.choice(listte) # computer generated number from the list
    
for i in range(3):
    answer = int(input("What is your guess?"))
    prevanswer = None # I came up with this but not really working?
    if answer == number:
        print "You got it!"
    elif answer < number:
        print "Nope, higher"
    # this elif is not working with below codes
    elif answer < number and answer > prevanswer:
        print "still higher"
    elif answer > number:
        print "lower!"
    prevanswer = i # also not working but this is what I came up with
```

An example execution scenario:

```
computer generated : 15

guess 1 : 17
prints "lower!"

guess 2: 10
print "make it higher"

guess 3: 12
print "still higher"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move the setting of `prevanswer = None` to before the loop. Otherwise, you're erasing the memory of what went before.

Second, take a look at your if/elsif code sequence. You have the right tests, but in the wrong order:

```
elif answer < number:
```

This will execute EVERY TIME answer is less than number. Below that you have:

```
elif answer < number and answer > prevanswer:
```

This is "good" code, in the sense that it should accomplish what you seem to want. But this is a MORE RESTRICTED case than the earlier one. That is, whenever answer < number, only SOMETIMES will answer > prevanswer. So you should check for the subset of possibilities BEFORE the general case of all answer < number.

Try this:

```
elif answer < number and answer > prevanswer:  # specific case
    ...
elif answer < number: # general case
```

And finally, don't set

```
prevanswer = i
```

but rather

```
prevanswer = answer
```